# TemplateDoesNotExist at /admin/portfolio/collection/add/ adminsortable/edit_inline/stacked.html

Tags: python, django, portfolio, django-apps

I installed the app [django-portfolio](https://github.com/dokterbob/django-portfolio), and can use runserver ok. When I go to the admin page to add a new object to the Collections model, I get the following error page.

```
TemplateDoesNotExist at /admin/portfolio/collection/add/
adminsortable/edit_inline/stacked.html
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/portfolio/collection/add/
Django Version: 1.8.3
Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist
Exception Value:    
adminsortable/edit_inline/stacked.html
Exception Location: C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\engine.py in find_template, line 146
Python Executable:  C:\Python27\python.exe
Python Version: 2.7.5
Python Path:    
['C:\\depot',
 'C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python27\\site-packages\\setuptools-5.4.1-py2.7.egg',
 'C:\\WINDOWS\\SYSTEM32\\python27.zip',
 'C:\\Python27\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\plat-win',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\lib-tk',
 'C:\\Python27',
 'C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python27\\site-packages',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Fri, 14 Aug 2015 17:12:32 +0800
Template-loader postmortem

Django tried loading these templates, in this order: Using loader
django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader: Using loader
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader:
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\templates\adminsortable\edit_inline\stacked.html
(File does not exist)
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\templates\adminsortable\edit_inline\stacked.html
(File does not exist)
C:\depot\depotapp\templates\adminsortable\edit_inline\stacked.html
(File does not exist)
C:\depot\portfolio\templates\adminsortable\edit_inline\stacked.html
(File does not exist)
```

Comment: did you add the adminsortable app to your installed_apps settings?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you haven't registered your app in `admin.py` file in your app directory.

Do this in `admin.py` in your app directory (and not project):

```
from django.contrib import admin
from app.models import MyModel

admin.site.register(MyModel)
```

Considering that your app name is `app` and your model name is `MyModel`

Do this for all the models in your app.